# How to write xpath for a soap response

Tags: java, xpath, soap

I want to validate the the lobType tag in the below response

```
                     <typ2:service>
                       <typ2:serviceId/>
                       <typ2:serviceDescription/>
                       <typ2:productInstance xsi:type="typ2:UpwareProduct" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                          <typ2:productInstanceId/>
                          <typ2:lobType>UPWARE</typ2:lobType>
                          <typ2:productAttributes/>
                          <typ2:resources/>
                          <typ2:associatedSiteReferences>
                             <typ2:string>SITE52</typ2:string>
                          </typ2:associatedSiteReferences>
                          <typ2:productName>Cloud Solutions</typ2:productName>
                          <typ2:productId>1157851548</typ2:productId>
                       </typ2:productInstance>
                       <typ2:associatedSiteReferences>
                          <typ2:string/>
                       </typ2:associatedSiteReferences>
                    </typ2:service>
```

The above is a snippet of a soap response. So this block will be repeated in the response with different values. I want to make use of the product instance tag and the values provided in it such as UpwareProduct to identify the tag.

Any help on this would be appreciated

Comment: I got the answer now ... it is //typ2:productInstance[@xsi:type='typ2:UpwareProduct']/typ2:lobType . Now I want to know how can i write it without the namespace?

Comment: You can use `[local-name()='myName'`] to avoid namespaces, e.g. https://cutt.ly/ShqjcYt

Comment: yes.. //[local-name()='productInstance'][contains(@[local-name()='type'],'UpwareProduct')]/[local-name()='lobType'... I was able to figure it out.. forgot to post the solution here

Comment: The above one is the answer. What do you mean when you are saying post it as an answer?